# Faulty server and greedy algorithm

Tags: python, greedy

The topic I am currently working on is called Greedy Algorithms. There is such a task

> There is a faulty server that can work without restarting no longer
> than t minutes. Restarting a server takes exactly one minute.
> You are given a list of times when there will be no requests to the server
> for a minute in the form of integers representing difference between
> no-request start time and current time, sorted increasingly. So that is the
> only possible time slots (each one is 1 minute time long) when the server
> can be restarted.
> You should output the minimum time of restarts needed for server to work for
> m minutes starting from now. If the server would have to restart when there
> are requests sent to it (i.e. it is impossible to fit all the restarts into
> the given time slots), output -1 insteed.

My naive solution looks so

```
def minRestarts(m, t, no_request_times):
    min_restarts = 0
    rest_times = []
    rt=t
    while t <= m:
        rest_times.append(t)
        t += rt+1
    for i in rest_times:
        if i in no_request_times:
            min_restarts += 1
        else:
            return -1
    return min_restarts
```

I'm not sure if there is anything greedy here but it seems to work on such test for example

```
m=100
t=20
no_request_times = [50]
```

It outputs -1. But on the other test

```
m=100
t=20
no_request_times = [20,41,62,83]
```

I have 4 as the output. But it must be -1? Or my answer is correct? May be I don't understand the task. Could you please tell me if it is correct.

Comment: Can you explain why you think the output should be -1?

Comment: Actually the answer 4 is for me ok and clear, (no_request_times coincide with 20 minutes periods plus one minute for restarting) The answer -1 I saw with a guy who I could trust). So my answer is ok?

Comment: Is my time complexity n times m? Can it be better with greedy method?

Comment: What is `n`?  How did you get a complexity of n*m?

Comment: n - number of elements in rest_times, m - number of elements in no_request_times. Two loops? ("in" operator will search in  no_request_times for m-time?)